# How can I create a translucent modal UIViewController?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I'd like to create a reusable UIViewController subclass that can be shown as a modal view controller over any other view controller.  One of the first things this reusable VC needs to do is pop up a UIActionSheet. In order to do this, I create a default (blank) view in my VC to show the action sheet from.

However, this looks bad because, when the modal vc pops up, the parent vc is hidden.  Thus it looks like the action sheet is floating over a blank background. It'd be better if the action sheet could appear to pop over the original (parent) vc.

Is there a way to achieve this?  Is it safe to simply grab the parent vc's view and animate the UIActionSheet from that?

Comment: having the same problem..
Any solution??

Answer (score 14):

After your modal view animates in, it is resized to be equal in size to its parent view. What you can do is inside your viewDidAppear:, take a picture of the parentController's view, then insert a UIImageView containing the picture of the parent at the back of your own view's list of subviews:

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Sneaky Background Image
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    // grab an image of our parent view
    UIView *parentView = self.parentViewController.view;

    // For iOS 5 you need to use presentingViewController:
    // UIView *parentView = self.presentingViewController.view;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(parentView.bounds.size);
    [parentView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *parentViewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    // insert an image view with a picture of the parent view at the back of our view's subview stack...
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    imageView.image = parentViewImage;
    [self.view insertSubview:imageView atIndex:0];
    [imageView release];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    // remove our image view containing a picture of the parent view at the back of our view's subview stack...
    [[self.view.subviews objectAtIndex:0] removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: For iOS 5 you need to use `presentingViewController` instead of `parentViewController`. I updated your answer to include that.

Comment: This mostly works great, but when I try it I get a 20 px gap at the top of the parent view image caused (I'm guessing) by the status bar. Any suggestions for correcting that?

Comment: Update: I've managed a fix by translating my image context 20 pixels upwards, but I'm still curious as to why I had to when it seems no-one else has?

Comment: It sounds as though the screenspace you're using differs from some. You might, for instance, not have the status bar up top showing for your app whereas others might.

Comment: @Mac You might need to set the modal view controller's `wantsFullScreenLayout` property to YES.

Comment: I'm having problems with this on a retina iPad. Anyone else? It just closes the app when running the renderInContext line

Comment: this shows a white screen for a second before showing the snapshot of the presentingViewController.  Is this really the best and only way to make a view controller background translucent?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply show it over your parent view controller by inserting view in a parent view.

Something like this:

```
PseudoModalVC *vc = ...//initialization
vc.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; // like in previous comment, although you can do this in Interface Builder
vc.view.center = CGPointMake(160, -vc.view.bounds.size.height/2);
[parentVC.view addSubView:vc.view];

// animation for pop up from screen bottom
[UIView beginAnimation:nil context:nil];
vc.view.center = CGPointMake(160, vc.view.bounds.size.height/2);
[UIView commitAnimation];
```

Comment: If you do this, you'll also need to make all the appropriate calls to methods like "viewWillAppear" in the displayed view controller.  UINavigationController and the modal system take care of this for you normally.

Answer (score -1):

Yep. Add it to the current view controller's view (or as a subview of the window) and animate it on-screen like Valerii said.

To remove it with an animation, do this (I'm assuming the modal view is 320 x 460 and it will slide down off the screen):

```
- (void)dismissModal
{
    // animate off-screen
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.50];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationDidStop:finished:context:)];

    self.view.frame = CGRectMake( 0, 480, 320, 460 );

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)animationDidStop:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context
{
    // don't remove until animation is complete. otherwise, the view will simply disappear
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
}
```