# show details of point on map - iphone

Tags: iphone, dictionary, touch

I have a custom map on my iphone app. I intend to put pins on this map. When the user clicks on a pin, I want a small animation to display the details of that location. If required the user can click on the detail and go to another screen for further processing. I am not sure how best to achieve this. I already have the scrollview and imageview for the map and can identify pin clicks on it. I now need to put the bit where the detail comes in. I would like this to be like a tableview cell, with multiple information. how do I add a tableview cell to that position in the imageview?

Can anybody help please?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this tutorial how annotation works... http://blog.objectgraph.com/index.php/2009/04/08/iphone-sdk-30-playing-with-map-kit-part-3/...

What you are looking for is there is a property called rightCalloutAccessoryView

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
  //Create a annotation view here
    annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = yourAnnotationButton;
}
```

which you can set a button up there. There is a delegate when this button clicked..

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
   // Go to your next view.
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, however I am not using Mapview at all, because this is not a street map. It is more like a building map which is an image, over which I need to put custom touch points. Can I still do that using annotations?

Comment: No map.. Annotations work on MapView only.. I think you should create custom views for your custom map...

Comment: This works out if there are very little building points.. You can create UIButtons as custom(which will be invisible) above the scrollview.. Now if you touch on a particular building(or say a button above it) present a small UIView with details.. Then keep a button on that view that will take you to next screen.

Comment: yes, I think I will have to do that, thanks. I want this uiview to be a transparent modal popup appearing at that particular point on the screen. Do you know if there is any sample code for a similar requirement? thanks for your help...

Comment: Dont know whether this works for you.. anyhow... https://github.com/matej/MBProgressHUD... You have to fetch the UItouch points by yourself... just google it.. sure you will find it...

Comment: thanks, I did the modal view by creating another view over the parent one, like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499298/how-can-i-create-a-translucent-modal-uiviewcontroller